# How to remove specific text from extensionattribute

Tags: regex, powershell

Task is to remove |text from an extension attribute but, but leave the rest of the text there.

I’ve tried the below but it does not remove it.

```
Set-ADUser -identity user -Clear     @{extensionAttribute1="|text"}
 Set-ADUser -identity user -Remove @{extensionAttribute1="|text"}
 Set-ADUser -identity user -Replace @{extensionAttribute1='|text',''}
```

Current string have multiple | characters that needs to remain.

Example. Some|unrelated|text&whatever
Need to remove just |text

Remain: Some|unrelated&whatever

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the old value first, manipulate it however you want, and then set it back on the object. Something like this should work:

```bsh
$oldValue = (Get-ADUser -Identity user -Properties extensionAttribute1).extensionAttribute1
$newValue = $oldValue.Replace('|text', [string]::Empty)
Set-ADUser -Identity user -Replace @{extensionAttribute1=$newValue}
```